# how to apply Numpy Vectorize instead of apply function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, apply

I have a pandas Dataframe as follows

```
data = {

'ID' : [0,0,0,0,0,1],
        
'DAYS': [293,1111,3020,390,210,10],
 

}



df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID','DAYS'])
    ID  DAYS
0   0   293
1   0   1111
2   0   3020
3   0   390
4   0   210
5   1   10
```

What I am trying to do is the simple apply function with the following condition and outputs column as boolean :

```
df['bool'] = df.apply(lambda x:( x['DAYS'] < 365),axis =1  )
```

and i would like to optimize this apply-lambda part..
I managed to do in numpy array

```
df['bool_numpy'] = np.where(df['DAYS'] <365 ,True ,False)
```

But I am struggling applying same thing for np.vectorize method.

```
def copy_filter(df):
    if df['DAYS'] <365:
        return True
    else:
        return False

a= np.vectorize(copy_filter, otypes = [bool])
df['bool_vectorize'] = a(df['DAYS'])
```

but gave me an error.
Any help would be appreciated.
and also, any other optimization technique on this problem would be great as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `apply` nor `vectorize` for this:

```
df['bool'] = df['DAYS'] < 365
```

output:

```
   ID  DAYS   bool
0   0   293   True
1   0  1111  False
2   0  3020  False
3   0   390  False
4   0   210   True
5   1    10   True
```

Comment: if I were to use vectorize , is it even possible?

Comment: @dakjdlajsl it is possible but for this case it is inefficient and unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, check @BENY's answer, but this is useless for this kind of operations. Note that vectorize will allow your function to accept a vector as input. It will **NOT** provide you with vector speed operations. This is only a wrapper around a loop

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to

```
def copy_filter(x):
    if x <365:
        return True
    else:
        return False
a= np.vectorize(copy_filter, otypes = [bool])
df['bool_vectorize'] = a(df['DAYS'])
df
   ID  DAYS  bool_vectorize
0   0   293            True
1   0  1111           False
2   0  3020           False
3   0   390           False
4   0   210            True
5   1    10            True
```

Comment: `def copy_filter(x): return x < 365` or even `lambda x: x < 365`